# The given key was not present in the dictionary (plugin for dynamics 365)

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I've made a plugin for primary entity 'incident' which is triggered on pre-operation stage. I am getting the error 'The given key was not present in the dictionary'. I am not sure what could be wrong here since it's my first plugin. The aim is to check if Case's serial number (zst_txtsn) exists in entity 'Warranty'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace ActiveWarranty
{
    public class Class1 : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            ITracingService tracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));


            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

    
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
    
                Entity Case = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];


                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                    (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

                try
                {
                    string serialNumber = Case.Attributes["zst_txtsn"].ToString();
                    Entity Warranty = new Entity("zst_warranty");

                    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("zst_warranty");
                    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "zst_name" });
                    query.Criteria.AddCondition("zst_serialno", ConditionOperator.Equal, serialNumber);

                    EntityCollection collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

                    if (collection.Entities.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Case["zst_activewarranty"] = true;
                    }
                    else if (collection.Entities.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Case["zst_activewarranty"] = false;
                    }

                    service.Update(Case);
                }

                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in FollowUpPlugin.", ex);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("FollowUpPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Any help would be much appreciated.
```

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the object is null, `.ToString()` will throw an error. You can try one of these.

```
string serialNumber = Case.Attributes["zst_txtsn"] + "";
```

or

```
string serialNumber = "";
if(Case.GetAttributeValue<string>("zst_txtsn") != null)
{
    serialNumber = Case.GetAttributeValue<string>("zst_txtsn").ToString();
}
```

Comment: I added your recommendation, thank you.
Though the problem seems to be again connected to the GUID...
'FaultException`1: Condition for attribute 'zst_warranty.zst_serialno': expected argument(s) of type 'System.Guid' but received 'System.DBNull'.'

Comment: @Morgana ya that’s what I thought, in earlier questions you said it’s lookup. Copy this error message and search in internet for troubleshooting tips and you should learn to debug the code too :)

Comment: It seems like you deleted the other post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812753/7920473 but from there I learnt that somehow you are filling the serial number lookup but it is not available in pre-create plugin. you should try post create or post update whenever the serial number lookup filled in case

Answer (score 1):

Few things to note

1-
If this plugin is registered on the create event
The service.update(case) will fail because Target has no id yet
In this case any updates should be done on the Target without a service.update

2-
If this plugin is registered  on the update event it’ll cause a loop if you’re not setting the filtering attributes properly for the trigger in the plugin registration tool. Additionally, since it’s on the pre stage, it should be enough to update the target with your boolean value to pass it to the platform.

In both cases above you should remove the service.update

3-
If zst_serialno is a lookup and you’re querying using the serial number text value
Then your query is wrong
You’ll have to use LinkEntities / $expand to query by related entity attributes